# How about Sunday vs How about on Sunday?

Tags: differences, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

"How about" are followed by nouns, clauses or Verb+ing. But is it grammatically correct to say "How about on Sunday?"

I got more results Googling "How about on Sunday?" than "How about Sunday?" Which is weird. Is there any grammatical explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, it is wrong to assume that a preposition should always be followed by nouns (or noun phrases), clauses or gerunds. It could be followed by a prepositional phrase. For example:

> *From behind* the cloud appeared the sun.

In the above sentence, both "from" and "behind" are prepositions and "behind the cloud" is a prepositional phrase functioning as a complement of the first preposition "from".

In your example, "on Sunday" is a prepositional phrase which is acting as a complement of the first preposition "about". It doesn't have any grammatical issue.

Also, you could consider a [gerund phrase](http://www.k12reader.com/term/gerund-phrase/) (going to the movies) is omitted because it was mentioned before. For example:

> A: How about going to the movies on Saturday?
>
> B. How about (going to the movies) on Sunday?

You can omit "on" in the second sentence:

> How about (going to the movies on) Sunday?

Comment: You can even omit the 'on' in other cases: How about going to the movies [this] Saturday. ...

Comment: @AmI Yes, definitely. The OP asked about the difference between "on Sunday" and "Sunday". On is optional. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

*How about* generally suggests a proposed answer to a question.  To answer the question, *when would you like to go to the museum,* one could say either *Sunday* or *on Sunday.*

Therefore, one might also say *how about Sunday?* or *how about on Sunday?*